# Multiple blocks in columns with the same height

Tags: html, css

Is possible to create layout as below in css (without flex)? Columns always must have 100% height. 
[image: layout]
Their content doesn't fill them from top to bottom, so I have this problem: 
[image: bad-layout]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fb8f049z/)

```css
.holder {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.holder > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder" >
        <div class="col-left" >
            <div class="first" >
                <h3>title</h3>
                <p>text text text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="image-bottom" >
                <img src="path/to/image" alt="Image" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-middle" >
            <div class="image-top" >
                <img src="path/to/image" alt="Image" />
            </div>
            <div class="second" >
                <h3>title</h3>
                <p>text text text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="image-bottom" >
                <img src="path/to/image" alt="Image" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-right" >
            <div class="image-top" >
                <img src="path/to/image" alt="Image" />
            </div>
            <div class="third" >
                <h3>title</h3>
                <p>text text text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us your HTML markup and CSS.

Comment: @Manwal [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fb8f049z/) I tried different ways and I think in this case my code wouldn't be necessary. May need to do it in a different way

Comment: Is the content of the "squares" going to change or is it going to be always the same?

Comment: @NeelShah I wrote: without flex.

Comment: @IvanRodriguezTorres change, must be responsive

Comment: Have you got a fixed height value anywhere..?

Answer (score 0):

Freewall plugin helps you to manage that effect.
[See the main page.](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/)